# disable the purchase button for all products in a specific category based on the day of the week

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to deactivate the button to all products belonging to a parent categories on specific days.

I tried this code but I can’t integrate the condition to set the days.
I should disable specific categories in based on the days of the week

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_product_description_add_cart_button', 1 );

function remove_product_description_add_cart_button() { // function for deleting ...
    // Set HERE your category ID, slug or name (or an array)
    $categories = array('ristorante-5');

    //Remove Add to Cart button from product description of product with id 1234
    if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', get_the_id() ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a switch statement, then define which categories are diabled on what day.

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_product_description_add_cart_button', 1 );
function remove_product_description_add_cart_button() { // function for deleting ...
 
    $disabled_categories = array(); 
    
    //gets day of week as number(0=sunday,1=monday...,6=sat)
    switch ( date('w') ) {
        case 0:
            $disabled_categories = array('ristorante-5');
            break;
        case 1:
            $disabled_categories = array('ristorante-5');
            break;
        case 2:
            $disabled_categories = array('ristorante-5');
            break;
        case 3:
            $disabled_categories = array('ristorante-5');
            break;
        case 4:
            $disabled_categories = array('ristorante-5');
            break;          
        case 5:
            $disabled_categories = array('ristorante-5');
            break;
        case 6:
            $disabled_categories = array('ristorante-5');
            break;
    }
    
    // Remove Add to Cart button from product description of product with id 1234
    if ( has_term( $disabled_categories, 'product_cat', get_the_id() ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }

}
```